# Jquery want to replace a - in html with a space

Tags: html, jquery, replace, append

I've tried a lot of things, and some of them work in console, but when I put them in the page they stop working.

Jquery is loaded on the site, but it will not replace the string. It either gives an error or seemingly silently fails.

```
$('h1').html($('h1').html().replace('-',''))
```

This works, but only in console and strips out all of them. I only need the first removed.

$('h1').html($('h1').html().replace('-',''))

Comment: What's your (relevant) HTML, in order that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - Please take the [tour] and read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question.  For starters, you can include a [mre] to the question for faster troubleshooting

Comment: You need a hyphen instead of space right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please

```
$('h1:first-of-type').html($('h1:first-of-type').html().replace('-', ' '));
```